# Basic Dictionary Operations in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm still new to Swift and have been having some issues with working with dictionaries, as well as Strings vs Characters. I'm using Swift 4 if it makes a  difference.

I want to take an array of Strings, and create a dictionary in which the keys are the first letters, and the values are an array, which would hold the entire string.

i.e. ["foo", "hello", "world", "wow"]

I want this to be a dictionary like ["F": ["foo"], "H": ["hello"], "W": ["world", "wow"]]

My code so far is giving me multiple errors. If someone could help me with refactoring to follow Swift conventions and best practices that would be awesome.

```
func convertArrToDict(_ arr: Array<String>){
    var dict: Dictionary = [String: [String]]()
    for word in arr {
        let firstLetter = String(word.characters.first!).uppercased()
        if (!dict.keys.contains(firstLetter)){
            dict[firstLetter] = [String]()
        }
        dict[firstLetter] = dict[firstLetter].append(word)
    }
    return dict
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: First you forgot to specify the return type. Second in Swift 4 you don't need to add `characters` just use `word.first`. Btw better to use if let just in case if there is an empty String in your array. Third append method doesn't return anything. You need to delete `dict[firstLetter] = `

Comment: `func convertArrToDict(_ arr: [String]) -> [String: [String]] {
    var dict: [String: [String]] = [:]
    for word in arr {
        if let first = word.first {
            let key = String(first).uppercased()
            if !dict.keys.contains(key) {
                dict[key] = []
            }
            dict[key]?.append(word)
        }
    }
    return dict
}`

Comment: Ok, that was really helpful. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: With Swift4, you can use a Dictionary initialiser like this:
let arr = ["foo", "hello", "world", "wow"]

let dict = Dictionary.init(grouping: arr, by: {$0.characters.first!})